# Problem with constraints in control.optimal.OptimalControlProblem

Tags: python, optimization

I started using the python control library to implement the inverted pendulum with model predictive control. I finally found out which system works and how I get the results for a nonlinear system of the pendulum. So I modified the code for a linear system but now I get the wrong results.
When I use constraints the input is the initial value and the states grow constantly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meVHx.png)

For the linear system I use a nonlinear input/output system. Then I set the constraints and costs and define the OptimalControlProblem. Finally I get the results with compute_trajectory.

```
import numpy as np
import control as ct
import control.optimal as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sc

def pendulum_update(t, x, u, params):
    g = params.get('gravity', 9.81)         
    k = params.get('friction', 0.1)    

    return np.array([
        x[1],            
        -k*x[1] + g*x[0] + u[0],           
        x[3], 
        u[0]
    ])

def pendulum_output(t, x, u, params):
    return x                            

pendulum = ct.NonlinearIOSystem(
    pendulum_update, pendulum_output, states=4, dt=0, name='pendulum',
    inputs=('u'), outputs=('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'))

x0 = np.array([1, 1., 1., 1.]); u0 = np.array([1.])
xf = np.array([0, 0., 0., 0.]); uf = np.array([0.])

Q = np.diag([1., 1., 1., 1.])         
R = np.diag([1.])               
def traj_cost(x,u): return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 + x[2]**2 + x[3]**2 + u**2

constraints = [ 
    opt.input_range_constraint(pendulum, [-20], [6]), 
    opt.output_range_constraint(pendulum, [-9, -9, -9, -9], [5, 5, 5, 5])]

timepts = np.linspace(0, 50, 100)
ocp = opt.OptimalControlProblem(
    pendulum, timepts, integral_cost=traj_cost, trajectory_constraints=constraints,     initial_guess=u0)

result = ocp.compute_trajectory(x0, return_states=True)`
```

When I don't set the constraints in ocp I don't get the right results but the states get controlled, so the input varies. I don't know how I can define the constraints different or weather the problem is due to the chosen system class. Has anybody here more knowledge in python control and knows how to implement MPC right?